# Page changing event ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

On these page I have a C# timer that start at the OnInit event.
I want stop it when the page changes or is closed.
What event I can use?

Comment: There is an Unload event, but if you are to implement something before the page is closed, you should do this on the client side since you cannot make further changes to the response stream when Unload is called. Please refer Page Life Cycle for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `IsPostBack` and then disable the Timer. When the page is closed the Timer will also stop.

```
if (IsPostBack == true)
{
     Timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: The timer does not stop when i change the page. I'm using the System.Timers.Timer

Comment: What do you mean by `change`. In my snippet the timer stops as soon as a button is clicked, textbox or dropdownlist change that have autpostback set to true etc.

Comment: like a redirect. My code is: `System.Timers.Timer t; 
   protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) 
   { 
    base.OnInit(e); 
    Load += NuovaPrestazione_Load; 
   }
  protected void NuovaPrestazione_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   { 
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    { 
     t = new System.Timers.Timer(20000); 
     t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent); t.Start(); 
    } 
   }
  private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
   { 
    
   }`